# How do I compare items in parallel Lists

Tags: python

If I have a list that's parallel to a list which contains items items in the same length, but the first list only contains items of type [1,2,3,4] ,and the other list contains items of [[1,2], [3,4], [4,4],[5,7]] how can I compare the items between the two list? to be more how can I compare the value at index 0 at the first list with the two values at index 0 in the second list. If the number inside the first list is lower than the one at the same index [0] and higher than the one at the same index [1]  inside the second list the program will return a str.

Comment: What would be your exepected output for the above?

Comment: Can you show expected output? What do you mean "compare" like return True/False if all elements are equal?

Comment: From one of your comments to one of the answers it seems you want to compare `list1[i]` to `max(list2[i])` or `min(list2[i])`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two lists like so:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,4],[5,7]]
```

You can put the lists in list2 into one list using list comprehension:

```
list3 = [item for sublist in list2 for item in sublist]
```

Then you can compare list1 and list3 by indexing them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [4,4],[5,7]]
result = [list1[i] in list2[i] for i in range(len(list2))]
# output [True, False, False, False]
```

Via `Zip` -

```
result = [item[0] in item[1] for item in zip(list1,list2)]
# output [True, False, False, False]
```

Comment: I want to check if the values contained in list2 are higher or lower than the values inside list 1.

Comment: Still, not clear. Please, edit your questions with proper example of your excepted output.